# Geometric meaning of $f_{k-1}(x_1, \cdots , x_{k-1}) = \int_{a_k}^{b_k}h(x_1,\cdots, x_{k-1}, x_k) d_{x_k}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose $I^k$ is a $k$-cell in $R^k$, consisting of all $X = (x_1, ... , x_k)$
such that $a_i \le  x_i \le b_i (i = 1, \cdots , k)$,

$I^j$ is the $j$-cell in $R^j$ defined by the first $j$ inequalities, and $f$ is a real continuous function on $I^k$.

Put $f = f_k$, and define $f_{k-1}$  on $I^{k-1}$ by

$$f_{k-1}(x_1, \cdots , x_{k-1}) = \int_{a_k}^{b_k}h(x_1,\cdots, x_{k-1}, x_k) d_{x_k}\cdots (**)$$.

The uniform continuity of $f_k$ on $I^k$ shows that $f_{k-1}$ is continuous on $I^{k- 1}$

Hence we can repeat this process and obtain functions $f_j$, continuous on $I^{k-1}$, such
that $f_{j-1}$ is the integral of $f_j$, with respect to $x_j$, over $[a_j, b_j]$. After k steps we arrive at a number $f_o$, which we call the integral of $f$ over $I^k$; we write it in the
form
$$ \int_{I^k}f(x)dx \mbox{ or} \int_{I^k}f$$
A priori, this definition of the integral depends on the order in which the
$k$ integrations are carried out. However, this dependence is only apparent.

> **What does the definition from $**$ even trying to tell us ? Can someone give me a geometric interpretation?**